# Magento 2 - How to change the error placement in a custom form on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, form-validation

I wish to place the error after the parent of the element being validated.
I tried to change the place via error placement function like below

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function($){
        var dataForm = $('#reward-points-form');
        dataForm.mage('validation', {
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.hasClass('input-reward')) {
                    error.appendTo('.input-error');
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

However, the script is not working as it's written in the Knockout HTML file.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add errorPlacement code in the JS file where validation function is called.

Before

```
validate: function() {
   return $(form).validation() && $(form).validation('isValid');
},
```

After

```
validate: function() {
    return $(form).validation({errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo('.input-error');
    }}) && $(form).validation('isValid');
},
```

This validate function was called on form submit action.

I wrote mixin for this change in my custom theme

```
define(
[
    'jquery'
],
function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var form = '#reward-points-form';
    return function (validateRewardPoints) {
        return validateRewardPoints.extend({
            validate: function() {
                return $(form).validation({errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo('.input-error');
                }}) && $(form).validation('isValid');
            },
        });
    }
});
```

and called mixin in requirejs

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Mirasvit_Rewards/js/checkout/cart/rewards_points': {
            'Mirasvit_Rewards/js/checkout/cart/rewards_points_mixin': true
        }
    }
}};
```